# Match CPU and Memory frequency for AMD X4 FX-4100 3.6GHz

Tags: memory, cpu, fsb

What memory type (1066 / 1333) should I buy for the AMD X4 FX-4100 3.6GHz processor? It's 3600 MHz with FSB of 2000 MHz as far as I know. Is it still relevant to match memory and cpu frequencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not relevant.

It really never was. It's true that a 1:1 ratio helped efficiency a bit on some configurations, but a 5% difference in speed trumps a 2% difference in efficiency any day, so faster is still better.

And it's certainly not relevant now. Your [AMD X4 FX-4100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulldozer_%28microarchitecture%29) doesn't even *have* an FSB. The HT bus doesn't connect to memory, but to the crossbar. So there's nothing to match.